# Angular: Rendering different component for different type of object

Tags: angular

In my model I have an array which can contain two different types of objects. How can I choose a different component to render an array item basing on the type of the item?

Comment: You need to write some code to do that ;)

Comment: I know that I'll need to write some code but I wander how to approach it.